# Rails STI conditional sub-classing from base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-attributes, sti

I'm developing a project where I have an entity which may have two kinds of assets: *Pictures* and *Videos*, basically.

Since I want all the assets to be on the same table and a single upload form for either *Pictures* or *Videos*, I'm using Single Table Inheritance having both *Picture* and *Video* descending from the *Asset* class. Also, I'll be running different validations/callbacks depending on whether it is a Video or a Picture.

I'm using paperclip to deal with the upload process, and my idea is to when uploading a file and creating an Asset with it, the application will instantiate the correct subclass (*Picture* or *Video*) depending on the mime-type of the uploaded file.

This is a sketch of my classes:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_uploaded_file :content, ...
end

class Picture < Asset
  validate :image_size
  ...
end

class Video < Asset
  after_save :convert_format
  ...
end
```

My idea is to implement a `before_save` callback on the *Asset* class and try to instantiate the correct class there, but I'm not sure how to do it or if it's a good idea.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you should favor fat models and skinny controllers, this to me seems better placed in the controller.  My primary rationale is that by doing this in your `Asset` model you are coupling a base type to its subtypes, which doesn't feel right to me (although I see APIs do it all the time).

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it came close to what I ended up doing and pointed me in the right direction: I discarded the nested modelling functionality and chose to save the nested model manually. The "factory" logic that creates the right sub-class is indeed in the Project controller, but it can be easily ported into its model, which I'll end up doing as soon as I finish the rest of the important stuff. A simplified snippet that depicts the solution is available at http://pastie.org/1522024.